# Pandas merging updated values with condition of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge a dataframe which contains number of vehicle supplies over regions to another data, which is a record of movement between regions.

The first data looks like this where start is the region id, supply_cnt is the number of supply for each region at the beginning of the day.

```
df1
start       supply_cnt
A              7.0
B              4.0
C              21.0
D              5.0
E              5.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

The second data looks like this
where start_dt and end_dt indicates departure time and arrival time of the movement.

```
df2
    start         end            start_dt             end_dt    
       B           A             00:00:42           00:11:27    
       A           D             00:12:58           00:15:52    
       F           G             00:21:07           00:29:28    
       G           K             00:34:08           00:39:49    
       K           K             00:34:10           00:45:59
```

I want to merge supply_cnt from df1 to df2's start region, but before merging I would like to update the supply_cnt in  df1 with df2.

For example, the first row of df2 is merged from df1 as it is, and if I update the supply of df1 with first row of df2, the supply of A and B will each increase and decrease by 1. So the merged value to the second row of df2 will be updated supply_cnt of A which is 8.

```
df2
    start         end            start_dt             end_dt       supply_cnt
       B           A             00:00:42           00:11:27           4    
       A           D             00:12:58           00:15:52           _    
       F           G             00:21:07           00:29:28           _    
       G           K             00:34:08           00:39:49           _
       K           K             00:34:10           00:45:59           _
df1
start       supply_cnt   new supply_cnt
A              7.0    ->     8   
B              4.0    ->     3
C              21.0   ->     21
D              5.0    ->     5
E              5.0    ->     5
... ... ... ... ...
```

The most challenging part of the problem is that I want to consider the **starting and ending time** (start_dt, end_dt) when merging  the supply count data.

For example, assume the start_dt of second row in df2 is **00:10:58 instead of 00:12:58**. Since 00:10:58 is faster than end_dt of row1 (00:11:27), I want to update 7 instead of 8.

What would be the best way to do this? I would sincerely appreciate some help.